# retrieve unique visits sql not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have this table

```
 visitors: ip,last_date (datetime)
```

When a different ip enters to the site in an specific day, it insert a new row, no matter if the ip is entering again.

Whit this sql statement I retrieve all unique ip visits in my site.
It works for an specific day, for example today (26/05/2020) and it grouped it by ip

```
  SELECT  v.*, max(last_date) as last_date1
  FROM visitors as v
  WHERE date(v.last_date) = :today
  GROUP BY v.ip 
  ORDER BY last_date1 DESC
```

Now I want to make an small daily report

```
 SELECT 
 COUNT(*) as count,
 DATE(last_date) AS last_date1
 FROM visitors 
 WHERE 1
 GROUP BY YEAR(last_date), MONTH(last_date), DAY(last_date)
 ORDER BY last_date1 DESC
```

`count`  retrieves all the times a especific ip has entered during the whole day. I jut want it to count it as 1.

**OUTPUT**

```
26/05/2020  76455
25/05/2020  34561
24/05/2020  45642
```

I want to retrieve unique ip visits. not the sum of the times every ip has entered during the day.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
26/05/2020  676
25/05/2020  543
24/05/2020  711
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want aggregation and `count(distinct ip)`.

```
select date(last_date) visit_day, count(distinct ip) no_visiting_ip
from visitors   
group by date(last_date)
order by visit_day desc
```

This counts how many unique `ip`s visited the site on each day. If you want the overall count of visits (regardless of whether the same `ip` visited more than once), then you can use `count(*)` instead.

Comment: @morty: as explained in my answer: `count(distinct ip)` counts each `ip` only once, even if it occurs more than once in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an aggregation:

```
SELECT date(last_date), count(*)
FROM visitors v
GROUP BY date(last_date)
ORDER BY date(last_date) DESC;
```